# Why does setIconBadge(final String badge) fail on MacOS Java 14 when okay on Java 11?

Tags: java, macos, swing

On MacOS Catalina using Java 14 I get the following exception

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The ICON_BADGE_NUMBER feature is not supported on the current platform!
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Taskbar.checkFeatureSupport(Taskbar.java:175)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Taskbar.setIconBadge(Taskbar.java:373)
    at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.Counters.resetCounters(Counters.java:407)
    at com.jthink.songkong.action.SongKongPrimaryTaskAction.init(SongKongPrimaryTaskAction.java:24)
    at com.jthink.songkong.action.FixFilesAction.actionPerformed(FixFilesAction.java:47)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
```

when I try to call `setIconBadge()`

This works okay using Java 11 so my question is why does it no longer with Java 14, is this on purpose or is it a bug ?

The code for `java.awt.Taskbar` has

```
public void setIconBadge(final String badge) {
        checkEventsProcessingPermission();
        checkFeatureSupport(Feature.ICON_BADGE_NUMBER);
        peer.setIconBadge(badge);
    }
```

Since I am passing it a String should it not be checking for **Feature.ICON_BADGE_TEXT** anyway ?

This code

```
 System.out.println("1:"+Taskbar.getTaskbar().isSupported(Taskbar.Feature.ICON_BADGE_NUMBER));
        System.out.println("2:"+Taskbar.getTaskbar().isSupported(Taskbar.Feature.ICON_BADGE_TEXT));
        System.out.println("3:"+Taskbar.getTaskbar().isSupported(Taskbar.Feature.ICON_BADGE_IMAGE_WINDOW));
        System.out.println("4:"+Taskbar.getTaskbar().isSupported(Taskbar.Feature.ICON_IMAGE));
        System.out.println("5:"+Taskbar.getTaskbar().isSupported(Taskbar.Feature.PROGRESS_VALUE));
        System.out.println("6:"+Taskbar.getTaskbar().isSupported(Taskbar.Feature.PROGRESS_VALUE_WINDOW));
        System.out.println("7:"+Taskbar.getTaskbar().isSupported(Taskbar.Feature.PROGRESS_STATE_WINDOW));
        System.out.println("8:"+Taskbar.getTaskbar().isSupported(Taskbar.Feature.USER_ATTENTION));
        System.out.println("9:"+Taskbar.getTaskbar().isSupported(Taskbar.Feature.USER_ATTENTION_WINDOW));
```

when run on MacOS Java 11 gives:

```
1:true
2:true
3:false
4:true
5:true
6:false
7:false
8:true
9:false
```

when run on MacOS Java 14 gives:

```
1:false
2:false
3:false
4:true
5:true
6:false
7:false
8:true
9:false
```

Comment: From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Taskbar.html#setIconBadge%28java.lang.String%29): “Some platforms do not support string values and accept only integer values. In this case, pass an integer represented as a string as parameter. This can be tested by `Feature.ICON_BADGE_TEXT` and `Feature.ICON_BADGE_NUMBER.`”  So, ICON_BADGE_NUMBER is minimal functionality;  ICON_BADGE_TEXT is an additional badge capability.  I don’t know why Mac badge support was removed in Java 14;  does `setWindowIconBadge` still work?

Comment: No, Ive just added some code to question that checks featuresset, as you can see the only change is that both ICON_BADGE_NUMBER and ICON_BADGE_TEXT are missing when move from Java 11 to Java 14

Comment: Sure looks like something that’s worth [submitting](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/) as a bug/regression.

Comment: ok, ive submitted as a regression bug.

Comment: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8245922

Comment: Although just got closed because I didnt create a test case, have now sent. Interestingly although worked ok with 11.0.7 and failed with 14.0.1 it now also fails on newly released 11.0.8

Comment: Ok reopened, and seems was due to Oracle disabluing functionality becuase of this other bug https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8230869